# Ajax-Solr Installation

Tags: solr

I am not able to set Ajax-Solr on my system.I did a bit of R&D on Ajax-Solr for the same .

I understood what it tries to do with the tutorial provided at https://github.com/evolvingweb/ajax-solr/ , but unfortunately, I am not able to able to set it up on my system.

I dont know how to integrate it with Solr. Into which directory of Solr instance does Ajax-Solr goes?(I know it doesn't matter where Ajax-Solr folder is kept but still just to to be sure)

I changed my solrURL to "http://localhost:8080/solr/" in reuters.js file.But still when i browse to "http://localhost:8080/solr/", it still shows the same backend Solr UI. (This may sound a kinda noobish)
Can you please suggest me how to get the Ajax-Solr front end UI ??
Please suggest something.
Thanks 
Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to deploy the Ajax-solr web application either on jetty or on some web server or app server.

If you want to deploy this in jetty, you have to create a WAR file out of th. S reuters sample.

If you have Apache on your machine, you can copy this to the htdocs folder, for eg.

Comment: Thanks for commenting. I am using tomcat and it psted it in webapps directory, but it still aint running. I am not able to get the Ajax-Solr UI on my localhost...Any suggestions??

Comment: Is the index page of Reuters demo coming up in tomcat?

Comment: Had it been there, I wouldnt have been here. LOL :) <br> Kindly suggest

Comment: I would follow the steps outlined here to install reuters app into Tomcat first. If you can get any static page to show up using a WAR, that is a good first step. http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/tutorials/j-tomcat/section4.html

Comment: Ajax-Solr isnt working yet. I am using Solr 3.4, edited the schema.xml file according to the tutorial provided at https://github.com/evolvingweb/ajax-solr/wiki/Reuters-tutorial. Changed my solrURL to "http://localhost:8080/solr/". but still it does not run.<br>
I am opening index.html via tomcat. It just shows the index1 template with loading circle in the result section and thats it. No calender,no map nothng at all. Where does the problm lies?<br>

Moreovr when i edited schema.xml and browse to "http://localhost:8080/solr/", it then pops up an error saying "Server errors in solr configratn"?

Comment: Apology for incorrect spellings. I just exceeded the limitation of the no.of characters.

Comment: Plus what does these statements mean?<br>
"If you are using your own Solr instance, you may want to change the values assigned to the fields keys."
AND<br>
" If you are not using your own Solr instance, you may want to change (or remove) the lines adding facet links for topics, organisations and exchanges."<br>


Kindly help. I am stuck with this for past 2 days now.<br>
Thanks<br>
Regards

Answer (score 2):

ajax-solr is just HTML, CSS, and JS. You can open the demo index.html from your harddrive in a browser and it will work (i.e. no webserver!). When you deploy, you can use Apache, Nginx, Tomcat, whatever. If you can make your webserver display an HTML file, you can make it display HTML files that include the ajax-solr JS files.